# List databases in Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server, backup, maintenance-plans

I'm trying to list all databases in existing Maintenance Plans. (or, more importantly those NOT in a plan...)

I'm using the followed code, based on [this blog](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/nebraska-sql-from-dba_andy/2014/05/07/help-i-need-a-list-of-my-maintenance-plan-jobs-and-schedules/):

```
Select DISTINCT p.name as 'Maintenance_Plan'
, RIGHT(smpld.line4,LEN(smpld.line4)-6) as 'Backup_Type'
, sp.subplan_name as 'Subplan_Name'
, smpld.line3 as 'Database_Names'
, job.name As 'Job_Name'
From msdb.dbo.sysjobs As job
join  msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_subplans sp
on sp.job_id = job.job_id
inner join msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_plans p
on p.id = sp.plan_id
join msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_log smpl
on p.id = smpl.plan_id 
and sp.subplan_id =smpl.subplan_id
join msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_logdetail smpld
on smpl.task_detail_id=smpld.task_detail_id 
where job.[enabled] = 1
and smpld.line3<>''
and smpld.line4 like '%Full%'
```

However, `sysmaintplan_logdetail.line3` is only a `nvarchar(256)` so doesn't store the complete list and I'm not sure what use this column is!  It's also comma separated and not easy to interrogate.
There is a `Command` column in `sysmaintplan_logdetail`.  This is `nvarchar(max)` and does indeed contain all the detail of the maintenance plan.  However it would take a lot of text manipulation to extract just a list of databases. Typical contents:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [SP2013_Enterprise_Search_LinksStore] TO  DISK = N''\\uk-sba-sql02\backups\SP2013_Enterprise_Search_LinksStore_backup_2015_11_16_113747_3942470.bak'' WITH  COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N''SP2013_Enterprise_Search_LinksStore_backup_2015_11_16_113747_3942470'', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

Can anyone suggest a simple robust way of extracting database details from maintenance plans?  I'm on SQL Server 2012.  I normally use the [Ola Hallengren Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/), but I've inherited these.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1):

```
-- This seems to be close to I think what you are needing 
-- shows dbs not in a maint plan (run pointing to msdb)  
select
t1.name as 'db_name',
--t2.database_name,
t1.crdate as 'date_created'
FROM [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases] as t1
left outer join
dbo.sysdbmaintplan_databases as t2
on t1.name = t2.database_name
where t2.database_name is null
and t1.name not in ('tempdb','msdb','model','master')
order by crdate desc
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  However, my `sysdbmaintplan_databases` table is empty! [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190308(v=sql.110).aspx implies this a legacy table from pre-SQL2005. I have data in `sysmaintplan_log, sysmaintplan_logdetail` and `sysmaintplan_subplans`, but nothing in tables beginning `sysdbmaintplan*`. Any other thoughts?